# How to update table column using checkbox?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to update my column `isApprove` to true or 1 when the checkbox is checked. As you can see in my view. I added a href to my checkbox to find the id of the checkbox that selected. But when checking the checkbox unfortunately in gives me a error. Did I missed something? Any help would appreciated!

> Missing required parameters for [Route: document.pending] [URI: documents/pending/approve/{id}]. (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\document\create.blade.php)

**View**

pending.blade.php

```
<tbody>
        @foreach ($pendingDocumentLists as $list)
        <tr class = "info">

        <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>

        <td>

        @if (Auth::id() == $list->approver_id)

        <form class = "form-inline" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <a href = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">
                        <input type = "checkbox" name = "approve" value = "yes">
                            <strong>Approve</strong>
                        </input>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class = "form-group">

                    <a href = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">
                    <input type = "checkbox" name = "reject">
                        <strong>Reject</strong>
                    </input>
                   </a>
                </div>

        </form>
            @endif
            </td>   
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Controller

```
public function updateIsApprove($id)
{
    $document = Document::find($id);

    if($approve == "yes")
    {
        $document->isApprove = 1;
        $document->save();
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/documents/pending',
[
   'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@documentsSentForApproval',
   'as' => 'document.pending',
]);

Route::post('/documents/pending/approve/{id}',
[
  'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateIsApprove',
  'as' => 'document.pending',
]);
```

Comment: The error included has nothing to do with your question.  The error is saying that no {id} is provided in the route / url.

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm just trying to set to true when I checked the checkbox. Is it valid If I passed to the checkbox value as my id? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you not checked input - nothing to send throw router. And in your router {id} attribute is required
You can add hidden input with the same name before your checkbox.

```
 <input type = "hidden" name = "approve" value = "no">
```

If checkbox will be checked, it rewrite hidden input value. And if checkbox not checked, you give the same name, but with another value.